# change the position of an item from a Popup in Kivy during runtime

Tags: python, kivy, popup, position, runtime

My objective is that I want to enter a decimal number into a `TextInput` from a `Popup`. Then the input will be used to change the `size_hint_x` of the button on the main screen during runtime.
Here is my attempt:

**Python File**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
Builder.load_file('question.kv')


class Pop_up(Popup):
    def open_window(self):
        self.open()
    def close_window(self):
        self.dismiss()
        number_typed = self.ids.text_box_in_popup.text
        a = main()
        a.change_position(number_typed)


class main(FloatLayout):
    def change_position(self, number_typed):
        movable_button = self.ids.movable_button
        movable_button.size_hint_x = number_typed
        # ~ this is the attempt of me trying to change the size_hint_x of the button
        # it doesn't produce an error but doesn't work either


class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    testApp().run()
```

**.kv File**

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<Pop_up>
    title: "type in a decimal number, I want to change the size_hint_x of the button to that number"
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.25, "center_y":0.25}
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id: text_box_in_popup
            size_hint: 1, 2


        Button:
            text: "update_position"
            on_release: root.close_window()
<main>
    Button:
        id: movable_button
        text: "movable_button"
        size_hint: 0.25, 0.25
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, "center_y":0.5}
        on_release: Factory.Pop_up().open_window()
```

I tried using `self.ids.movable_button.size_hint_x = number_typed` but it doesn't work although it doesn't generate any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `close_window()` method, the line:

```
a = main()
```

is creating a new instance of the `main` class. However, this new instance is not part of your GUI and any changes you make to it will have no effect on what you see on the display. In order to do what you want, you must access the `main` instance that is in your display. You can get a reference to that instance by replacing the above line with:

```
a = App.get_running_app().root
```